# How to change the value of the hidden field in the foreach on change event?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have input fields and foreach conditions on my page.

```
<form action="process.php" name="employee" method="post">

  <input type="text" name="name" class="onchangefield">
  <input type="hidden" name="haschange[name]" class="haschange" value="0" />
    <?php 
            $i=1;
            $arrayName = array('1','2','3');
            foreach ($arrayName as $key => $value) {?>
            <input type="file" name="slider[]"  class="fileupload onchangefield">
            <img src="<?php echo $value;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="haschange[slider][<?php echo $i;?>]" class="haschange" value="">
    <?php $i++; } ?>
</form>
```

What I am doing is, I have a hidden input field and When the user changes or edits the input field then I am adding 1 from 0 in the hidden fields.

There is no issue with the single input fields, I am getting the issue on foreach condition. When I upload the file then it's not changing the value.

I am using the below script.

```
$(".onchangefield").change(function() {
  var selector = $(this).next() //get next input..
  selector.val($(this).val() != "" ? 1 : 0) //depending on value change value of next
});
```

I am using the below code

```
<div class="col-xxl-9 col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
<div class="innerWrpperpadding bg-white border-bottom pb-5">
<div class="input_fields_wrap addsliderField">
 <button class="addSlider bg-blue mb-3 ">Add Image <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
 <div class="row">
    <?php 
       // $sliders=explode(",", $companyInfo['slider']);

       $haschange = array('1','2','3');
       $arrayName = array('1','2','3');
       $i=1;
       foreach ($arrayName as $key => $h) {
          //print($key);
       
        ?>
    <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 mb-3">
       <div class="upload_doc">
          <?php if($i>=2){?>
          <div class="closefile"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close_img"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></div>
          <?php }?>
          <input type="file" name="slider[]"  class="fileupload noofslider onchangefield">
          <input type="hidden" name="haschange[slider][<?php echo $key;?>]" class="haschange" value="<?php echo $haschangeed['slider'][$key];?>" />
          <div class="uploadInfo">
             <div class="upload_icon"></div>
             <span>Supports: JPEG, PNG <br />Max Size: 2MB<br />Dimensions Max:1100*600</span>
          </div>
          <div class="previewImage"></div>
          <div class="afteruploadedImage uploadedCompany"> <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>admin/company/assets/images/uploads/slider/<?php echo $h;?>" alt="" class="singlePreview" />
             <input type="hidden" name="slider[]" value="<?php echo $h;?>">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <?php $i++;} ?>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
 let fileUploadCount = $(".noofslider").length;
  const max_fields = 5;
  const $wrapper = $(".addsliderField .row");
  const $previewwrap = $(".input_fields_wrap .row");
  const $add_button = $(".addSlider");
  //const template = '';

  //let fileUploadCount = 1;
 

  //alert(fileUploadCount);

  $add_button.click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (fileUploadCount < max_fields) {
      fileUploadCount++;
      $wrapper.append('<div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 mb-3"><div class="upload_doc"><div class="closefile"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close_img"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></div><input type="file" name="slider[]"  class="fileupload noofslider onchangefield"><input type="hidden" name="haschange[slider]['+fileUploadCount+']" class="haschange" value="0" /><div class="uploadInfo"><div class="upload_icon"></div><span>Supports: JPEG, PNG <br />Max Size: 2MB<br />Dimensions Max:1100*600</span></div><div class="previewImage"></div></div>');
    }
  });

 
   });

$(".onchangefield").change(function() {
  var selector = $(this).hasClass("fileupload") ? $(this).next().next() : $(this).next() //get next input..
  selector.val($(this).val() != "" ? 1 : 0) //depending on value change value of next
});

    </script>
```

Comment: The next tot he selector is image. Check if this statement is correct by changing  selector.val($(this).val() != "" ? 1 : 0) to selector.attr('data-test', 1) and verify with inspect element whether image tag has got data-test attribute

Answer (score 1):

The below solution depends on your working code or you might want to tweak the code as required.

Wrap the input file element with a dummy wrapper.

```
<form action="process.php" name="employee" method="post">

  <input type="text" name="name" class="onchangefield">
  <input type="hidden" name="haschange[name]" class="haschange" value="0" />
    <?php 
            $i=1;
            $arrayName = array('1','2','3');
            foreach ($arrayName as $key => $value) {?>
            <div class="dummy-wrapper">
            <input type="file" name="slider[]"  class="fileupload onchangefield">
            <img src="<?php echo $value;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="haschange[slider][<?php echo $i;?>]" 
                class="haschange" value="">
              </div>
    <?php $i++; } ?>
</form>
```

And update the js like

```
$(".onchangefield").change(function() {
  var selectorWrapper = $(this).closest('.dummy-wrapper') //get next input.
  selectorWrapper.find('.haschange').val($(this).val() != "" ? 1 : 0) //depending on value change value of next
});
```

**Tested and working in my local**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="process.php" name="employee" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="name" class="onchangefield">
    <input type="hidden" name="haschange[name]" class="haschange" value="0" />
    <?php 
            $i=1;
            $arrayName = array('1','2','3');
            foreach ($arrayName as $key => $value) {?>
            <div class="dummy-wrapper">
            <input type="file" name="slider[]"  class="fileupload onchangefield">
            <img src="<?php echo $value;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="haschange[slider][<?php echo $i;?>]" 
                class="haschange" value="">
                </div>
    <?php $i++; } ?>
    </form>

    <script>
    $(".onchangefield").change(function() {
    var selectorWrapper = $(this).closest('.dummy-wrapper') //get next input.
    console.log("change",$(this).val()) //checkpoint // confirms, this function is executed on change
    console.log(selectorWrapper.find('.haschange').length) // checkpont // confirms there is an input element
    selectorWrapper.find('.haschange').val($(this).val() != "" ? 1 : 0) //depending on value change value of next
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: Let me check your answer

Comment: If I am not wrong you have added the div dummy-wrapper and the same class called in the script. I tried but it's not changing the value.

Comment: Let me check again

Comment: Yes, I tested but it's not working with the input field now.

Answer (score 0):

In your `foreach` loop, the `Input` after the `File` is not the hidden one, it's the IMG tag.

So when you do `$(this).next()` you are actually selecting the IMG tag and changing its value.

Since the hidden field doesn't appear, you can simply change its position in the foreach to be right after the file input.

```
<?php 
$i=1;
$arrayName = array('1','2','3');
foreach ($arrayName as $key => $value) {?>
    <input type="file" name="slider[]"  class="fileupload onchangefield">
    <input type="hidden" name="haschange[slider][<?php echo $i;?>]" class="haschange" value="">
    <img src="<?php echo $value;?>">
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: Yes, let me implement your solution.

Comment: I had not moved the input, I had just copied your previous code. [facepalm] Move the Input type hidden below the input type file, I've updated my answer to reflect

Comment: Yes, I know I added a hidden field after the file type. That was a mistake from my side while copy paste

Answer (score 0):

Other way will be checking if the input which is change has class `fileupload` or not depending this you can change your selector and then change your value there.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".onchangefield").change(function() {
  var selector = $(this).hasClass("fileupload") ? $(this).next().next() : $(this).next() //get next input..
  selector.val($(this).val() != "" ? 1 : 0) //depending on value change value of next
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="process.php" name="employee" method="post">

  <input type="text" name="name" class="onchangefield">
  <input type="text" name="haschange[name]" class="haschange" value="0" />
  <br/>
  <input type="file" name="slider[]" class="fileupload onchangefield">
  <img src="<?php echo $value;?>">
  <input type="text" name="haschange[slider][<?php echo $i;?>]" class="haschange" value="">
  <br/>
  <input type="file" name="slider[]" class="fileupload onchangefield">
  <img src="<?php echo $value;?>">
  <input type="text" name="haschange[slider][<?php echo $i;?>]" class="haschange" value="">
  <br/>
  <input type="file" name="slider[]" class="fileupload onchangefield">
  <img src="<?php echo $value;?>">
  <input type="text" name="haschange[slider][<?php echo $i;?>]" class="haschange" value="">
  <br/>

</form>
```

Comment: I am getting the dynamic fields but don't know why it's not working with my code. Let me check again

Comment: Make sure classes are same .Also , is above your html generated or not ?

Comment: If I generate the dynamic fields then it's not working

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I have updated the code in the question. can you check it once?

Comment: Hi , so you need to change value of `<input type="hidden" name="slider[]" value="<?php echo $h;?>">` also i.e : You need change value at two places ?